# Does Rubin-Rosenbaum sensitivity analysis include selection bias as special case?

Tags: causality, sensitivity-analysis

According to pg 2 of the pdf [http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~rosenbap/BehStatSen.pdf](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/%7Erosenbap/BehStatSen.pdf), "however, this alternative method takes account of sampling variability and is applicable to any kind
of response; see, for instance, [25, 26, 29], and Section 4 of [28] for detailed discussion. Alternative methods of sensitivity analysis are described in [1, 5, 8, 9, 14, 18, 19, 23, 24], and [33]." [23] refers to selection bias.

$Q:$ Does Rubin-Rosenbaum sensitivity analysis include selection bias? Or should one do selection bias sensitivity analysis separately?

$Q':$ If not, what does the review mean by "alternative"? Were they unrelated or totally different direction?

$Q'':$ When Rubin-Rosenbaum sensitivity analysis is sufficient? All it tests is that there is an unmeasured confounding which affects both outcome and treatment and which may not directly affect selection in sample indicator. Selection bias seems something different from that sensitivity analysis from the DAGs.